# How can I update/add unlockables into my app without an update?

Tags: ios

I need to add unlockables to my application, but the problem is that I don't want to have to send out an update every time that I want to add something new. I have read a bit about servers and JSON and XML. I just wanted to check to see if anybody else had a better idea?

Comment: Why not include conditional code in your app for 'unlockables'. That eliminates server updates.

Comment: Well, there is code that allows the user to access the unlockable. My main problem is that I have to add a lot of unlockables at different times. Basically my app will allow a company to purchase something from me and I will add their logo inside of the app. So I don't know what company will want to do this, and I don't want to add an update for one small image. So, it seemed like there would be an easier way to achieve this. @sangony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about something like a logo change then, short of an app update, the only option you have is  getting it from an outside source such as a server transmission. But now you are talking about in-app purchases which, if you have not already, should read up on.

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

Server based image and/or text transmissions are easily done and if I understand your last comment correctly, these updates would not be very frequent anyway.

Comment: Okay ill check her out thanks!